# How to insert a list in postgres query

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

Below is the query that I use for getting a weekly report, so I have connected Postgres with python notebook. My issue is I don't know how to give a list to the SQL command because I have already given the time zone function to it, please see the query and help out if possible.

Below function is for getting an epoch pair

```
def get_week_epochs():

year_first_monday = '2019-12-02'
today = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
monday = pd.date_range(start=year_first_monday, end=today, freq='7D')
monday_epochs = (monday.astype(int)/(10**9) - 19800).astype(int)
epoch_pairs = list(zip(monday_epochs[:-1], monday_epochs[1:]))


return epoch_pairs
```

and this is my list

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

my existing query, that I want to add a list to it

```
query = "Select a.id, a.name from ABC as a inner join XYZ as b on a.id=b.user_id where a.created_at >= '{}' and a.created_at '{}'".format(t_i, t_f)
```

For the above query, I want to add another condition i.e

`a.id not in (list)`

how can I do this??

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your list to a tuple. For example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

query = """
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM ABC a
INNER JOIN XYZ b
ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE a.id NOT IN {}""".format(tuple(lst))

print(query)
```

Output:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM ABC a
INNER JOIN XYZ b
ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE a.id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
```